# How can I get the same/to pass parameters between decorator and decorated function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, decorator, python-decorators

In this case I want to pass `_source_dir_abs:str` into decorator.

I tried to mimic the same process that Flask has for routing to pass parameter from decorator to function it is decorated. But this makes the parameter interpreted as a literal string and not as a variable.

```
@dec_check_abs("<_source_dir_abs>")
def walk_return_dir_nofolder(_source_dir_abs:str) -> list:
    w = walk(_source_dir_abs)
    d = [d for d, fol, fil in w if len(fol) == 0]
    return d
```

I tried with `@dec_check_abs(_source_dir_abs)` it returns an error of `NameError: name 'source_dir_abs' is not defined`

```
def dec_check_abs(*args_1):
    def decorator(_func:FT):
        def wrapper(*args_2, **kwargs):
            for i in args_1:
                if not check_abs(i):
                    """Raise warning."""
                    napw()

                    if _func.__annotations__["return"] == bool:
                        return False
                    else:
                        return None

            return _func(*args_2, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: What is `dec_check_abs`?

Comment: The decorator, I think everything that starts with "@" is a decorator right?

Comment: Why is this downvoted :\?

Comment: Yes, I can see that it's a decorator, but beyond that I know nothing of this "`dec_check_abs`".  Where is it defined?  What is its definition?

Comment: Decorator wraps _function object_. Function wasn't called at all when this happened, so whatever you try to pass to decorator _constructor_ does not exist yet. You may handle it in dectorator `__call__` dunder, but that's it.

Comment: I edited `dec_check_abs()`.

Comment: Łukasz Rogalski, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem answered in a Reddit thread, https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5wnygi/how_can_i_get_the_same_parameters_between/.

Here is my code now.

```
def dec_check_abs(*params):
    def decorator(func):
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            for param in params:
                val = bound.arguments[param]

                if not check_abs(val):
                    """Raise warning."""
                    napw()

                    if sig.return_annotation == bool:
                        return False
                    else:
                        return None

            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@dec_check_abs("source_dir_abs")
def check_isfolder(source_dir_abs:str) -> bool:
    return os.path.isdir(source_dir_abs)

@dec_check_abs("source_dir_abs", "dest_dir_abs")
def copy_fileorfolder(source_dir_abs:str, dest_dir_abs:str) -> bool:
    shutil.copy2(source_dir_abs, dest_dir_abs)
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the point of decorators. You don't pass the argument in the decorator declaration; the function returned by that decorator accepts the arguments and can pass it on to the wrapped function if necessary.

So the decorator would look something like this:

```
def dec_check_abs(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if ... do your check on args here...:
            return func(*args)
        else:
            print('No, bad caller.')
    return wrapper
```

and you would just use it as:

```
@dec_check_abs
def walk_return_dir_nofolder(_source_dir_abs:str) -> list:
    ...
```

Comment: I am pretty sure Flask did it with `@app.route("/api/mic/<_clientName>")`. What is that if not an argument?

Comment: That is indeed an argument. But it's not at all what you asked; your question appeared to be about how to pass an argument from the function to the decorator.

Comment: This is a Flask example, http://pastebin.com/RRXVuvFs. You see, you can get the same `_clientName` for both decorator and the decorated function. I want to achieve the same.

Comment: But that example doesn't say what you claim it does. What is happening there is that the decorator wrapper is passing the argument on to the decorated function.

Comment: Forget my claim. I want to have something like my Flask example. How can I do that?

Comment: But I can't see how that would apply in the case of your `dec_check_abs` decorator. As far as I can see, you just want to call `check_abs` on the arguments to `walk_return_dir_nofolder`; which is exactly what I show you in my code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/n3smRz5f another example, I think this clear enough on what I want.

Comment: Sorry, no. I have already explained how you use the arguments passed to the function in your decorator; I can't see at all what you are trying to achieve if it's not that.

Comment: Ah okay you tried at least :). I will just hard code the argument with `**kwargs`.